# Maintain commas in .csv format

Tags: php, string, csv, foreach

My script is working perfect but I cannot resolve how to maintain commas w/out destroying my .csv format.

The only way I have been able to get this to work is by preg_replace() and stripping out the commas.. But this is not adequate. I've tried several different hacks to no avail.

Here is what I have now:

```
    foreach ($rows[$i] as $value) {
    $insert .= preg_replace("/,/", "", $value) . ",";
    //$insert .= mysql_real_escape_string($value) . ",";
}
```

Comment: Why's it not adequate? Sure, you can use `str_replace()` (and should) instead of regex, but your regex _should_ work. `Not adequate` covers an awful lot of situations; please clarify.

Comment: If you created your cvs files with `fputcsv` and read them with `fgetcsv` you would not have this problem...

Comment: Of course it's not adequate... using a set of nutcrackers to stir your coffee isn't adequate either... use the right tool for the job... use fgetcsv() and fputcsv() for reading and writing csv files, and you wouldn't have any problem that needed a hack solution

Comment: fputcsv is not an available option as I am working with an earlier version of php (4) and fputcsv is only available for 5 >. I actually attempted your suggestion earlier. And in terms of "Adequate" the problem is the commas are stripped from any data that contains commas. And if there is a company name such as : My Company, LLC .. the comma is stripped from LLC.

Comment: There are plenty of `fputcsv` php 4 implementations on the web that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this

```
 foreach ($rows[$i] as $value) 
 {
    $rowparts = explode(",",$value);
    // Do some validation, i.e. columcount, string specfier an so on
    $insert .= implode("; ", $rowparts ) . "\r\n";
 }
```

Just a thought, you could also build in an validation for the parts of your csv-rows.

Answer (score 0):

As other commenters have noted, the correct solution to this issue is to use [fputcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php).

You really shouldn't be using php4 either - it's way out of date.  It hasn't been updated in 4 years.